# How do I find the starting and ending tiles of a checker?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that finds the maximum number of paths a checker can take. It starts on the tiles in a board's starting row, and ends on the tiles in the board's ending row. The problem is that I am unable to figure out how to map the machine-readable tile labels to the human-readable tile labels.

```
1 2 3 4            A   B
R|B|R|B          R|B|R|B
B|R|B|R          B|R|B|R
R|B|R|B          R|B|R|B
B|R|B|R          B|R|B|R
1 2 3 4          1   2
```

While my program is calculating paths, I want it to be able to see the board the way it is depicted on the left. However, while it is finding the end tile with the maximum number of paths, I want it to read the board the way it is depicted on the right. I'm thinking of having a "halved" array where each tile number is stored twice in a row. For example, it could be [1, 1, 2, 2] instead of [1, 2, 3, 4]. I'm just not sure how to implement this. Here is part of my program:

```
// place checker on each bottom-row black space, and count paths
for (int checkerPos = 1; checkerPos < rFringe; checkerPos += 2)
{ // always starts in bottom-left-hand corner
    board = resetBoard(board); // clear board for new checker
    board[bottomRow][checkerPos] = 1; // put checker on starting location
    // calculate # of paths from starting location to each end tile
    for (int r = bottomRow - 1; r > 0; r--) // start in row above bottom, and end right before top fringe (i.e. row 0)
    {
        for (int c = 1; c < rFringe; c++)
            board[r][c] = board[r + 1][c - 1] + board[r + 1][c + 1];
    }

    // find end tile with max paths
    max = board[1][1]; // default max is upper-left space on checkerboard
    for (int c = 2; c < rFringe; c++) // don't re-check first column and don't check fringe
    {
        // compare this to other top-row boxes to find one with highest value
        if (board[1][c] > max)
        {
            max = board[1][c];
            startLoc = checkerPos; // GETS WRONG VALUE
            endLoc = c; // GETS WRONG VALUE
        }
    }

    maxInfo[maxCount] = max; // add current piece's max to max array
    maxInfo[maxCount + 1] = startLoc; // save start location
    maxInfo[maxCount + 2] = endLoc; // save end location
    maxCount += 3; // go to next empty slot in array
}
```

As you can see, without a way to map `checkerPos` and `c` to `startLoc` and `endLoc`, I am unable to get accurate values for these variables.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, I implemented a "halved" array.

```
int[] halved = new int[size]; // used for mapping the machine-readable tile #s to human-readable tile #s and letters
// populate halved array
for (int halvedIdx = 0, i = 1; halvedIdx < size - 1; halvedIdx += 2, i++)
{
    halved[halvedIdx] = i;
    halved[halvedIdx + 1] = i;
}
```

In addition to this, I changed

```
startLoc = checkerPos;
endLoc = c;
```

to

```
startLoc = halved[checkerPos];
endLoc = halved[c];
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution. If anyone has suggestions, feel free to comment.

**UPDATE**

A problem with this solution is that, if the board's size is odd, checkerPos ends up being outside of the halved array's bounds.